# how to validate a filename using asp.net regular expression validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

i have the following code to validate my file name entered using regular expression validator
but even after enter correct file name format, its hitting error saying enter valid filename

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtFileName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="FileNameRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server"
   ErrorMessage="Enter valid FileName"
   ControlToValidate="TxtFileName"
   ValidationExpression="^(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Like example.txt,example.pdf even after enter its  asking enter valid filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your regex requires the filename to start with a backslash. Also, your filenames may only contain the lowercase form of letters. Is that intentional?

Also, you're repeating your repeated group, a surefire recipe to bring your server down to its knees with [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) once someone enters an invalid filename that's more than a few characters long.

Perhaps

```
ValidationExpression="(?i)^[\w\s0-9.-]+\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$">
```

would be more suitable?

Comment: No i dont want to start my file name with backslash, my requirement is like to validate file name like exmaple.txt,example.php, i should not allow any special character other than (.)dot

Comment: So then there's your solution - have you tried my regex? However, currently that regex also allows space, `-` and `_` (as the old one did).

Comment: ValidationExpression="(?i)^([\w\s0-9.-]+\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$"

Comment: I am getting error saying parsing "(?i)^([\w\s0-9.-]+\.(txt|gif|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx)$" - Not enough )'s.